# What is the formula for expressing $f(x,y,z)$ in terms of second-order partial derivatives?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

By the fundamental theorem of calculus $f(x) = f(0) +f'(0)x + \int_0^x \int_0^v f''(u)dudv$.

What is the explicit formula (using integration) for expressing $f(x,y,z)$ in terms of  $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial z^2}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial y}$, $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial x \partial z}$, and $\frac{\partial^2 f(x,y,z)}{\partial y \partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial x}|_{0,0,0}$, $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial y}|_{0,0,0}$, $\frac{\partial f(x,y,z)}{\partial z}|_{0,0,0}$ and ${f(x,y,z)}|_{0,0,0}$?

What is the explicit formula for expressing any function $f(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ in terms of integrals of second-order partial derivatives, first order partial derivatives evaluated at the origin and $f(0,\ldots,0)$?

Comment: Do you know what domain you'd like the function to be twice-continuously-differentiable in? In what way do you expect the derived formula to be unique, if at all?

Comment: Not looking for uniqueness. I'm searching for a formula that looks like:

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = f(0,0,0)
 + \sum x_j \frac{\partial f(x_1,x_2,x_3)}{\partial x_j}|_{0,0,0}
+ \sum_{j_1,j_2} \int_0^{x_j} \int_0^{s_j}\frac{\partial^2 f(v_1,v_2,v_3)}{\partial v_{j_1} \partial v_{j_2}}|_{(?,u_j,?)} du_j ds_j$

Comment: I'm trying to pinpoint why you're aiming at utilizing knowledge of the second derivatives in an open set, but of first derivatives at a single point, for example. This will change the way you'd construct a formula, since there are quite a few possibilities.

Comment: For the problem that I'm dealing with, I know the value of the function and the first derivatives at only a single point. I know the value of the second derivatives everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the function in question is defined on a star-shaped domain with the 'known' point (say, the origin) as its center, you might define $g$ on $[0,1]$ by
$$g(t) = f(t{\bf x})$$
Then the fundamental theorem gives us
$$f({\bf x}) - f({\bf 0}) = g(1) - g(0) = \int_0^1 g^\prime(t)dt = \int_0^1 \left(g^\prime (0)+\int_0^t g^{\prime\prime}(s)ds\right)dt.$$

We can now verify that $g^\prime(t) = df(t{\bf x}){\bf x}^T$ and (assuming $f$ is scalar-valued) $g^{\prime\prime}(s) = {\bf x}d^2f(s{\bf x}){\bf x}^T$, which would give us
$$f({\bf x}) = f({\bf 0}) + df({\bf 0}){\bf x}^T + \int_0^1\int_0^t{\bf x}\left(d^2f(s{\bf x})\right){\bf x}^Tdsdt$$

Now, dealing with a vector-valued $f$ doesn't require many adjustments; one would only need to evaluate each component separately. Relaxing assumptions on the domain could further complicate computation, but the same general approach still works (using a given curve from the origin to the point of interest). However, we did assume $f$ to be $C^2$ (or rather, $C^1$ and almost-everywhere twice-continuously differentiable) in all cases.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I needed.